# Why does the $c$-theorem work?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, renormalization

The question is rather simple. I understand that the  [$c$-theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C-theorem) proves that there exists a function that decreases monotonically with the RG flow and other properties. What I don't understand is: why does the $c$-function gives information about the flow of the coupling constants {$g_i$}? It seems to me that the theorem just proves the existence of a function but I don't see how this constrains the evolution of the coupling constants.

Comment: Which kind of information do you mean?

Comment: I've been told that the fact that a c function exists proves that the rg flow goes from a fixed point in de uv to one in the ir discarting the possibility of limit cycles,  chaos or other strange behaivour

Comment: Well yes, isn't it obvious from the fact that $c$ monotonically increases forbids cycles?